# How to reload map when spinner option is selected?

Tags: java

I am working with Google Maps API, and I want to add a filter to my map that causes certain markers to be hidden depending on what spinner option is selected. How can I make it so the map reloads when the option is selected, so that the user can filter while using the map? I am currently using java.